# Convert temperature data from Kelvin to Celsius in multiple columns

Tags: r, mutate

I have a dataset with multiple columns of temperature data in Kelvin. I want to convert it to celsius.

```
Sr. StationID   MaxTemp   MinTemp  MeanTemp  Prec   
1   5320         280       270       275      1.2
```

I am using this code which helps to convert only one column (MxTemp). I want to add more column names.

```
DF %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with("MaxTemp"),.fns = function(x) x - 273.15))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `starts_with`, you could use `ends_with`:

```r
DF %>% mutate(across(.cols = ends_with("Temp"),.fns = function(x) x - 273.15))
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF) # make it a data.table

tcols = grep("Temp", names(DF))
DF[, (tcols) := .SD - 273.15, .SDcols = tcols] # columns updated by reference
```